# fine-uploader azure blob with SAS WEBAPI

Tags: jquery, azure, fine-uploader

enter image description hereI’m working on a pure html / javascript project that uploads a file in chunks to Azure Blob storage.

I have a HTML5 / jquery solution that works perfectly for large video files.  It will create and use a SAS token to upload large files into Azure storage using MVC 4 and WEBAPI.
I cannot use this solution because the HTML5 uses a method called split() that is not supported in Safari or iOS portable phones.  So I started looking at the FineUploader solution.

I was able to get the signature endpoint working with WEBAPI that returns a SAS that looks like this…
'
https://sike42.blob.core.windows.net/videos/CAM00281.mp4?sv=2013-08-15&sr=b&sig=PMwXaWLreN2uyHANtEBH1%2BwGB5%2FPjJ2h%2F5ML3pHev%2FM%3D&se=2014-04-18T01%3A12%3A33Z&sp=rwl

I turned Debug on and was able to see that immediately after it returns from the 
signature: { endpoint: '/api/signature'

I get an error

NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://one27.0.0.1:1369/%3Cstring%20xmlns=%22http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/%22%3Ehttps://sike42.blob.core.windows.net/videos/CAM00281.mp4?sv=2013-08-15&sr=b&sig=PMwXaWLreN2uyHANtEBH1%2BwGB5%2FPjJ2h%2F5ML3pHev%2FM%3D&se=2014-04-18T01%3A12%3A33Z&sp=rwl%3C/string%3E"

I’m a little confused on how to fix this problem and thought I would ask for some help after googling and looking on the support for an answer.

It looks like some XML is getting between the SAS and the URL or something weird is going on.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#fine-uploader").fineUploaderAzure({

        debug : true,
        request: {
            endpoint : 'https://sike42.blob.core.windows.net/videos/'

        },
        signature: {
            endpoint: '/api/signature'
        },
        uploadSuccess: {
            endpoint: '/success'
        }


    });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

I cant post the errors that I'm seeing in firebug because this embedded html editor will not allow onetwentyseven.zero.zero in the post. Very Frustrating.

So I published one link that works (it uploads a file in chunks using Azure SAS)

roku.azurewebsites.net

and one link that you can use to see the errors in firebug yourself using fineuploader.js

roku.azurewebsites.net/default.html

I paid $78 for this js code  because I thought i could use it for chunking on an iPhone without use of jquery slice()   (note : jquery slice is not supported on the iphone )   .... Please help with some support.

Thank You

```
    const string STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME = "sikeXXXXXX";

    const string STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY = "LccVXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX==";
    static List<String> ALLOWED_CORS_ORIGINS = new List<String> { "roku.azurewebsites.net" };
    static List<String> ALLOWED_CORS_HEADERS = new List<String> { "x-ms-meta-qqfilename", "Content-Type", "x-ms-blob-type", "x-ms-blob-content-type" };

    //     x-ms-meta-qqfilename,                   x-ms-blob-type,   x-ms-blob-content-type,Content-Type


    const CorsHttpMethods ALLOWED_CORS_METHODS = CorsHttpMethods.Delete | CorsHttpMethods.Put | CorsHttpMethods.Post | CorsHttpMethods.Get;
    const int ALLOWED_CORS_AGE_DAYS = 5;
    const string SIGNATURE_SERVER_ENDPOINT_ADDRESS = "http://*:8080/signature/";
    const string UPLOAD_SUCCESS_ENDPOINT_ADDRESS = "http://*:8080/success/";
```

in the method startServer();

how can i run this in an apicontroller if it enters a infinite loop ???

should I put this code in a worker role instead ?

headers =

Cache-Control   private
Content-Length  3529
Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf-8
Date    Tue, 13 May 2014 02:37:54 GMT
Server  Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version    4.0.30319
X-Powered-By    ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles   =?UTF-8?B?QzpcMjAxM1xTaWtlNDJcU2lrZTQyLldlYlw8c3RyaW5nIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOlxzY2hlbWFzLm1pY3Jvc29mdC5jb21cMjAwM1wxMFxTZXJpYWxpemF0aW9uXCI+aHR0cHM6XHNpa2U0Mi5ibG9iLmNvcmUud2luZG93cy5uZXRcdmlkZW9zXEFueXRoaW5nNTEzMjAxNCAyMzc0NCBBTQ==?=
Request Headers
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Content-Length  2462553
Content-Type    video/mp4
Cookie  __RequestVerificationToken=0j8Re7pnVCpuw4sU59jYAioM9ESekxdTt6pudAdNPQyJTRjxyN65tMhZkAg1wDE_C464UDLGv3kTN2djj87SNwz8oc_UZNnVCXEYoL7y9Po1
Host
Referer /default.html
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0
x-ms-blob-type  BlockBlob
x-ms-meta-qqfilename    CAM00281.mp4

html =  A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (<).

P.S.  I would have included SS of the error ... but I need 10 rep points and have not earned them yet. ;-(

Comment: Please show all of your log messages via developer tools in the browser.  Most likely your signature server is not returning the proper response.

Comment: OK ....   I return a string from the /api/signature GET and it is ...   https://sike42.blob.core.windows.net/videos/CAM00281.mp4?sv=2013-08-15&sr=b&sig=sksyjRPnCDN74k349wosiae2303GEesRY90HQtF7J%2B0%3D&se=2014-04-19T00%3A42%3A34Z&sp=rwl

Comment: OK ....   I return a string from the /api/signature GET and it is ...   https://sike42.blob.core.windows.net/videos/CAM00281.mp4?sv=2013-08-15&sr=b&sig=sksyjRPnCDN74k349wosiae2303GEesRY90HQtF7J%2B0%3D&se=2014-04-19T00%3A42%3A34Z&sp=rwl   I use same code in an Ajax call and it will upload to Azure Blob storage ....   So this is why i'm stuck and looking for some help.   It is a strange bug.

Comment: [Fine Uploader 4.4.0] PUT request for 0 has failed - response code 500                    id = 0
xdrError = undefined

Comment: There is likely some issue with your code or environment.  Please provide a transcript of the http requests between Fine Uploader, your server, and Azure.  You can do this quite easily using the network tab in chrome dev tools.

Comment: what is the best way to provide transcript ?  Comment window allows only 600 chars.  External links or can I include an attachment?

Comment: You will need to edit your question.

Comment: Can I send SS to you on the issue?   I can document it much better in an email that has SS details.   Thank You

Comment: What is SS exactly? All support is done via StackOverflow so others may benefit from the solutions. Email support is [offered](http://fineuploader.com/purchase_form.html), though.

Comment: A screen shot would be an easy way to communicate details.  I cant just cut and paste the response / header / html because it has links.  My status on StackOverflow only allows me to post two links.  So what work around would make communication the easiest ?

Comment: I have a page that will upload a file in chunks using Azure / SAS and blob storage.  I simply want to to the same thing with fineuploader.  roku.azurewebsites.net has a working solution.   roku.azurewebsites.net/default.html has the fineuploader demo for Azure that I'm having trouble getting working.

Comment: Both are using WEBAPI but the fineuploader example is calling the GET() and causing an error on the PUT().  The Get() is just returning the SAS as a string, and the post is throwing an error

Comment: [link](http://roku.azurewebsites.net)

Comment: <http://roku.azurewebsites.net>

Comment: instead of returning SAS as a string from the Get() should I have it return a HttpResponseMessage and put the sas in Content ?

Comment: here are the errors on the put()

Comment: XML = The request entity's media type 'video/mp4' is not supported for this resource.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'Object' from content with media type 'video/mp4'.</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace> at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync[T](HttpContent content, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters,

Comment: Response Headers =  Cache-Control no-cache
Content-Length 950
Content-Type application/xml; charset=utf-8
Date Tue, 13 May 2014 22:28:47 GMT
Expires -1
Pragma no-cache
Server Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles =?UTF-8?B?QzpcMjAxM1xTaWtlNDJcU2lrZTQyLldlYlxhcGlcc2lnbmF0dXJlMVw=?=

Comment: Request Headers = Accept text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Content-Length 2462553
Content-Type video/mp4
Cookie __RequestVerificationToken=MV0UUrx4Ew7iY-nLCfKMzneFVESSG52YjOcaAuEDluPWCiE2Nx83Ry-VteazGsAEwWbiimrdtClWOJH10xezB-i3wjgti-hQmFA3q5-iG3k1
Host 127.0.0.1:1369
Referer http://127.0.0.1:1369/default.html
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0
x-ms-blob-type BlockBlob
x-ms-meta-qqfilename CAM00281.mp4

Comment: Params =  method PUT
bloburi http://sike42.blob.core.windows.net/videos//3f14da05-a2b4-4f40-b8b9-e324e03df13b.mp4
qqtimestamp 1400020127874?sv=2013-08-15
se 2014-05-13T22:58:48Z
sig GBVIcoYoRa/v2TOY8SFDp+ojTGA/4DlEijdA5/Rw7Xk=
sp rwl
sr b

Comment: Im doing this because of one line of code .... will not work on older versions of iphone.

Comment: var fileContent = selectedFile.slice(currentFilePointer, currentFilePointer + maxBlockSize);

Comment: I have to find a way to chunk a file in JS without using slice()

Comment: You can't chunk a file in JavaScript without slice.

Comment: Thx...  now I know that,  I did get everything working and want to share the hoops I had to jump through.  So far i tested it on Android, Windows desktop, Mac desktop and will do iPhone tonight.   Thank you again :-)

Comment: On the front end : How do I fire and event after a file has been selected / before start upload? I need to show a div.

Comment: Have a look at the events section on our docs site, there are many events that fall into this category.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with what I think was the same problem as you:

- My WebAPI method was returning a valid SAS URL to FineUploader;
- FineUploader would attempt to upload the file to my local server instead of to the SAS URL.
- Curiously, the SAS URL was showing up somewhere in the URL that FineUpload was ultimately using.

The problem turned out to be that WebAPI was automatically serializing the SAS URL as JSON. This resulted in the SAS URL being malformed -- a few extra characters were being added -- and FineUploader was confused by the resonse. In your case, it looks like the SAS URL is being serialized as XML, based on the *schemas.microsoft.com* text that's present.

With that understanding I bypassed WebAPI's automatic serialization. Below is a working implementation of my `GET /api/sas` method. Note: `GetSasForBlob` is pulled directly from the [Sample Azure Server](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader-server/blob/master/C%23/azure/FineUploaderAzureServer.cs).

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string bloburi, string _method)
{
   var accountAndKey = new StorageCredentials(STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME, STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY);
   var sas = GetSasForBlob(accountAndKey, bloburi, _method);

   var content = new StringContent(sas);
   return new HttpResponseMessage {Content = content};
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am trying your solution but I have problem with cross-origin requests. I've got my code deployed to azurewebsites.net and when I am trying to upload file it says: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load statuscode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StringContent, Headers:{  Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8}. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.` Didn't you experienced this error?

Comment: Here's some documentation on [Enabling Cross-Origin Requests in Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api).

Comment: I added `[EnableCors(origins: "azurewebsites.net", headers: "*", methods: "*")]` to my `Signature` action but I can't see any changes of headers in Chrome Dev tools. Also the response is `Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8` and raw response looks like this: `StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StringContent, Headers:
{
  Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
}`

Comment: Had the same issue when trying to use `IHttpActionResult`. Returning `Ok(blobUrlWithSas)` returns the blob url inside double quotes (as it get serialised to JSON) which breaks fine uploader. Using `return ResponseMessage(new HttpResponseMessage { Content = new StringContent(blobUrlWithSas) });` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in comments below John's answer, I had some problems with his solution. Firstly I thought that I have problem with cross-origin requests since Chrome Dev Tools shown this message error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load statuscode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StringContent, Headers:{ Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8}. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
```

Unfortunatelly the problem was not with my setting of `CORS`. I set `CORS` exact same like in [FineUploader's example](https://github.com/FineUploader/server-examples/blob/master/C%23/azure/FineUploaderAzureServer.cs) and I knew that problem must be somewhere else.

Finally I found problem and I am willing to share my solution with you so if someone in the future has same problem he or she can resolve it in a less time than I resolved it. Problem was that John's snippet returned malformed response message like this:

```
StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StringContent, Headers: { Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8 }
```

Since FineUploader was waiting for string containing SAS URI it was not working. I don't understand why in error message I get what I was getting but OK. There is simple solution for this, instead of returning `HttpResponseMessage` with content created by `StringContent` I simply returned `Content`:

```
    public ActionResult Signature(string bloburi, string _method)
    {
        // here provide your credentials
        var accountAndKey = new StorageCredentials(StorageAccountName, StorageAccountKey);
        // GetSasForBlob was provided in FineUploader's example
        var sas = GetSasForBlob(accountAndKey, bloburi, _method);

        var storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(accountAndKey, true);
        // ConfigureCors was also provided in FineUploader's example
        ConfigureCors(storageAccount);

        return Content(sas);
    }
```

I also slightly edited `ConfigureCors` method so it doesn't need extra method for just outputting settings to console (since this is used in MVC 5 project).

```
    private static void ConfigureCors(CloudStorageAccount storageAccount)
    {
        var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        var newProperties = blobClient.GetServiceProperties();

        newProperties.DefaultServiceVersion = "2013-08-15";
        blobClient.SetServiceProperties(newProperties);

        var ruleWideOpenWriter = new CorsRule()
        {
            AllowedHeaders = AllowedCorsHeaders,
            AllowedOrigins = AllowedCorsOrigins,
            AllowedMethods = AllowedCorsMethods,
            MaxAgeInSeconds = AllowedCorsAge
        };

        newProperties.Cors.CorsRules.Clear();
        newProperties.Cors.CorsRules.Add(ruleWideOpenWriter);
        blobClient.SetServiceProperties(newProperties);
    }
```